# Prevent entities from stealing each other's mapped child entities in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, persistence

I have two entities, **Subject** and **Lesson**. Subject has OneToMany relationship with Lesson.

My database already has 2 sets of objects:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "wow",
    "lessons": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "difficulty": "hard"
        }
    ]
}
```

and

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "wow2",
    "lessons": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "difficulty": "hardy"
        }
    ]
}
```

Entities are defined as follows

```
@Entity
public class Lesson {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String difficulty;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Subject.class)
    private Subject subject;
}

@Entity
public class Subject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=false, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id")
    private List<Lesson> lessons;
}
```

I want to prevent this object to be saved successfully since it is stealing (1, "wow")'s lesson:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "wow2",
    "lessons": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "difficulty": "hard_overrriden"
        }
    ]
}
```

Manually iterating over all lessons is an obvious way, but I want an easy solution.

**EDIT** : 
My solution fixes the stealing problem but, creates another too

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(updatable = false)
private Subject subject;
.
.
.
@OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="subject", orphanRemoval=true)
private List<Lesson> lessons;
```

This fixes the stealing problem but deletes the orphan if I want to disassociate **lesson** from **subject**.

On removing, `orphanRemoval = true` it just stops disassociating lesson from **subject**.

Disassociation object is as follows:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "wow",
    "lessons": []
}
```

Comment: I would appreciate if someone can suggest a better title.

Comment: Your mapping is incorrect. Here's how a bidirectional OneToMany is mapped: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: But anyway, when associating an existing lesson to a subject, check that it doesn't have any other subject. All you need is an `if` block.

Comment: Yes. But it's incorrect. You must use mappedBy. As described in the documentation.

Comment: Is this mapping fine @JBNizet